# How to achieve Adafruit Feather M0 Sleep & Wake on External Interrupt using any Pin?

Tags: arm, interrupt, microprocessors, adafruit, samd21

I am currently working on a low-power project using the **Adafruit Feather M0** microprocessor. A requirement of my project is to be able to sleep the CPU and wake it again using an external interrupt triggered from the MPU6050 accelerometer.

I have tested the following code sample from GitHub - it works successfully! The question that I need answering is how to I alter this sample code to work on Pin 13 of the feather, rather than pin 6.

```
#define interruptPin 6
volatile bool SLEEP_FLAG;

void EIC_ISR(void) {
  SLEEP_FLAG ^= true;  // toggle SLEEP_FLAG by XORing it against true
  //Serial.print("EIC_ISR SLEEP_FLAG = ");
  //Serial.println(SLEEP_FLAG);
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(3000); // wait for console opening

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), EIC_ISR, CHANGE);  // Attach interrupt to pin 6 with an ISR and when the pin state CHANGEs

  SYSCTRL->XOSC32K.reg |=  (SYSCTRL_XOSC32K_RUNSTDBY | SYSCTRL_XOSC32K_ONDEMAND); // set external 32k oscillator to run when idle or sleep mode is chosen
  REG_GCLK_CLKCTRL  |= GCLK_CLKCTRL_ID(GCM_EIC) |  // generic clock multiplexer id for the external interrupt controller
                       GCLK_CLKCTRL_GEN_GCLK1 |  // generic clock 1 which is xosc32k
                       GCLK_CLKCTRL_CLKEN;       // enable it
  while (GCLK->STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);              // write protected, wait for sync

  EIC->WAKEUP.reg |= EIC_WAKEUP_WAKEUPEN4;      // Set External Interrupt Controller to use channel 4 (pin 6)


  PM->SLEEP.reg |= PM_SLEEP_IDLE_CPU;  // Enable Idle0 mode - sleep CPU clock only
  //PM->SLEEP.reg |= PM_SLEEP_IDLE_AHB; // Idle1 - sleep CPU and AHB clocks
  //PM->SLEEP.reg |= PM_SLEEP_IDLE_APB; // Idle2 - sleep CPU, AHB, and APB clocks

  // It is either Idle mode or Standby mode, not both. 
  SCB->SCR |= SCB_SCR_SLEEPDEEP_Msk;   // Enable Standby or "deep sleep" mode

  SLEEP_FLAG = false; // begin awake

  // Built-in LED set to output and high
  PORT->Group[g_APinDescription[LED_BUILTIN].ulPort].DIRSET.reg = (uint32_t)(1<<g_APinDescription[LED_BUILTIN].ulPin);  // set pin direction to output
  PORT->Group[g_APinDescription[LED_BUILTIN].ulPort].OUTSET.reg = (uint32_t)(1<<g_APinDescription[LED_BUILTIN].ulPin); // set pin mode to high

  Serial.println("Setup() Run!");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  if (SLEEP_FLAG == true) {
    PORT->Group[g_APinDescription[LED_BUILTIN].ulPort].OUTCLR.reg = (uint32_t)(1<<g_APinDescription[LED_BUILTIN].ulPin); // set pin mode to low
    Serial.println("I'm going to sleep now.");
    __WFI();  // wake from interrupt
    SLEEP_FLAG = false;
    Serial.println("Ok, I'm awake");
    Serial.println();
  }
  //Serial.print("SLEEP_FLAG = ");
  //Serial.println(SLEEP_FLAG);
  PORT->Group[g_APinDescription[LED_BUILTIN].ulPort].OUTTGL.reg = (uint32_t)(1<<g_APinDescription[LED_BUILTIN].ulPin);  // toggle output of built-in LED pin
  delay(1000);

}
```

As per the pinout diagram and Atmel datasheet, I am struggling to work out which changes to make to allow pin 13 to operate in the same way as pin 6.

[Atmel Datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2772/atmel-42181-sam-d21_datasheet.pdf)
[image: Feather M0 Pinout Image]

The obvious solution is to change the following lines...

```
#define interruptPin 13
EIC->WAKEUP.reg |= EIC_WAKEUP_WAKEUPEN1;      // Set External Interrupt Controller to use channel 4 (pin 6)
```

I suspected channel 1 (WAKEUPEN1) due to the ENINT^1 next to pin 13 on the pinout diagram. But this didn't work, the code pin operation did not exhibit the same behaviour as the pin 6 setup.

I would be very grateful for any suggestion of how to implement this code working on Pin 13. Many thanks for your support.

Comment: GitHub Project Source: https://github.com/ProjectsByJRP/M0_Sleep_External_Int

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an authority here, and your code looks correct to me.

Except, the pin out shows Pin 13 is the built-in LED line, and you manipulate LED_BUILTIN several places in your code.  That's almost certainly conflicting with your attempts to use 13 as an interrupt line.